# Export to HTML presentation using reveal

Tags: org-export

I'm completely new to Emacs (just saw a presentation made with that using export to HTML presentation via reveal). I'm not able to find a way how to setup Emacs to show the option Export to HTML presentation, which was active on my colleagues laptop. I'm using Windows 10. Would you please give me a guide or point me somewhere, where I can find each and every step?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll want to install `ox-reveal`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [yjwen/org-reveal: Exports Org-mode contents to Reveal.js HTML presentation. - github.com](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/) :

1. Install it from melpa
2. Set it up with:

   ```
   (require 'ox-reveal)
   (setq org-reveal-root "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reveal.js@3.7.0/")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Along with the previous answer provided by @whatacold.

from melpa using the `use-package` see the code below

```
;; Install ox-reveal
(defvar client-multiplex nil)
(use-package ox-reveal
  :config
  ;;(setq org-reveal-root "C:/path/to/reveal.js-master")
  (setq org-reveal-root "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reveal.js"
    org-reveal-mathjax t))
```

Note: the commented part can be used instead of the `cdn` however you will have to download the reveal and place the folder into your desire path.

I tested on `windows 10` and it works quite nice. Well, you said that you are quite new, you can take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psDpCpcIVYs&t=408s), (the explanation is really nice, you will learn a lot of emacs stuff). However, i ll give some steps in order to generate your first presentation and export it.

After the compilation of your `init.el` file in emacs having NO ERRORS. Do the following.

Generate an `Org` file (see the example bellow)

```
#+REVEAL_THEME: sky
#+OPTIONS: num:nil
#+TITLE: My awesome presentation
#+AUTHOR: Your name
* Slide 1
  here goes some text
* Slide 2
** Subslide 1
** Subslide 2
* Slide 3
  #+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (roll-in)
  - list item 1
  - list item 2
    | a | b | c |
    |---+---+---|
    | 1 | 2 | 3 |
    | 4 | 5 | 6 |
    |---+---+---|
* Slide 4
  #+BEGIN_SRC python
    def f(x):
    return x + 1
    print f(5)
  #+END_SRC

#+REVEAL_THEME: is the theme of your choice. in my case was `sky`, `#+OPTIONS: num:nil` those are the options in this case i decide to remove the numeration of the slides if you change it to `t` you will see how the numbers appear (please test it, also there are more options you can search for those in internet), `#+TITLE:` and `#+AUTHOR:` i think they do not need explanation right?.
```

The first start is the actually the first slide, two starts are the subslide, Note: Those are headings and subheading in org mode. in slide 3 you can create tables and set attributes using `#+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (roll-in)`, remove `:frag (roll-in)` and see what happens. In slide 4 i decided to place some code, look the code must be placed between the `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC` the word `python` is the actual type of code to be displayed and sometimes compiled, remove it and take a look what happens.

Finally, if you want to show or export your presentation into `HTML` press `C-c C-e` and another window opens showing some options before pressing something read all the provided options. There is specifically one option:

Press the capital letter `R` `Export to reveal.js HTML Presentation` then press the capital letter `B` `to File and Browse` and automatically `firefox` opens your presentation.

Look, i am not an expert. However, if someone has a better idea please share it

**PLEASE: take a look at the website provided by @whatacold.**