# Creating a portable html file using Org-reveal

Tags: linux, org-reveal

## Description of problem

I am new to Emacs and want to write a presentation using Org-reveal that can be opened on other computers. I have read that I need to create a portable file using `#+OPTIONS: reveal_single_file:t` in the `:REVEAL_PROPERTIES:` section. When exporting the file using C-c C-e R B, this generates the following message in the Echo Area: `Cannot read https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reveal.js/dist/reveal.css`. My question is how to resolve this?

## Information about my set up and similar questions

To answer this short question, you will likely need more information about my settings, which I am providing in the following:

### REVEAL PROPERTIES

```
:REVEAL_PROPERTIES:
#+REVEAL_REVEAL_JS_VERSION: 4
#+REVEAL_THEME: serif
#+OPTIONS: timestamp:nil toc:1 num:nil
#+OPTIONS: reveal_single_file:t
:END:
```

### Emacs config

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (use-package ox-reveal
  :ensure ox-reveal) ;; ensures org-reveal package
  (setq org-reveal-root "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/3.0.0/") ;; location of reveal code to get it to work
;; (setq org-reveal-root "home/tiberius/reveal.js") 
 (setq org-reveal-mathjax t) ;; allows putting math typotations into org mode
```

### Linux version and installation of reveal

I am using Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria (Cinnamon desktop). I used the following [instructions to install reveal on Linux](https://www.imaginelinux.com/install-reveal-js-ubuntu/).

### Similar questions

I have found a similar question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47419/export-to-html-presentation-using-reveal). However, this question is concerned with how to set this up on Windows, whereas I am working with Linux Mint.

## Wrapping up

The file reveal.css is in the reveal.js/dist folder with the following permissions `"-rw-rw-r--"` suggesting to me that it ought to be readable. I have tried to refer Emacs in my configuration file to the path in my home directory instead (see commented line in the config file). However, this has generated a similar error message: `Cannot read home/tiberius/reveal.js/dist/reveal.css`. Any advice would be much appreciated. I hope I have provided the relevant information, but let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: Can you `curl https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reveal.js/dist/reveal.css` from the command line?

Comment: `home/tiberius/reveal.js` is a relative pathname, so depending on what your current directory is, it may or may not work. Try making it absolute: `/home/tiberius/reveal.js`.

Comment: NickD, I did both. I don't know which of these did the trick, but it works now. Thank you so much, really happy it's working now!!

Comment: Probably the second: the first one just confirms that you can get the file from the remote server. But once you've downloaded it, you can use the local file for which the absolute pathname is necessary.